# Local website starts in directory

Tags: visual-studio-2010, iis, web, visual-studio-2012

I'm setting up a website with VS express for web and IIS 7.5 express and have gotten it to work, but the start page of the site on my local points to a directory instead of the home.aspx page. I've set the home.aspx page as the start page in vs, but still no luck. I've clearly forgot to set something up since I updated to vs 12.

I've enabled directory browsing in IIS because it was throwing an error to enable it before. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in inetmgr.msc (IIS control panel), select your site, and then select "Default document" from the features pane. add a new entry with 'home.aspx' and click the up arrow until it is the top entry in the list.

or you can add a  tag to your web.config
http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/defaultdocument

Comment: Kind of weird how I have to add a default document even when I've set it as the start page, but thanks. I guess it's easier to stick with a default start page name in the future.

Comment: well, the start page is just an indication to the debugger to start by requesting that page. it doesn't affect any code, though it could set the default doc in the webconfig if MS so choose.